# using wireless to send images

Tags: ros, kinect, wireless

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new here. I want to save the rgb images and depth images from kinect and using wifi to send to another laptop.Is that accessible? If it's accessible, what packages do I need? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201724/using-wireless-to-send-images/) by [tomwoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21476/tomwoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should actually be quite easy with ROS. You will need a driver that allows the first computer to grab data from the Kinect and publish the data as ROS messages. Likely any of the following packages could work: [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch), [openni2_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch), [freenect_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch).

Then if your second computer is on the same network as the first, and your [ROS network](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) is configured correctly, then the second computer should be able to subscribe to messages produced on the first computer (including RBG and Depth streams from the Kinect).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2